# Responsive text size with absolute position over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Over the responsive calendar image I would like to have a text with the date. When the screen is resized to that point that the image will start to resize, the text over that image should resize as well, so that it stays the same relative to the image width and height.

[image] [image]

I have achieved that by using javascript as I was unable to do it only with CSS. My question is, how can I do that only with CSS. Is it possible? If yes, please show that in the code that I have created on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bej0od7r/

HTML:

```
<div class="datePictureHolder">
  <img class="img-responsive" alt="News Icon" src="http://shrani.si/f/u/13K/4rB6HshN/news-icon.png"/>
  <div class="datePictureText">
    <div class="year">2017</div>
    <div class="day">25. Feb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
ResizeDateIcons();

window.onresize = function () {
    ResizeDateIcons();
};
function ResizeDateIcons() {
  // constants
  var imageWidth = 150; // width and height must be the same
  var dayTextSize = 36; // text size on maximum image width
  var yearTextSize = 23; // text size on maximum image width
  var yearLineHeigh = 70;
  //
  var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var allDayTexts = document.getElementsByClassName("day");
  var allYearTexts = document.getElementsByClassName("year");
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
    if (allImages[i].alt === "News Icon") {
      allDayTexts[j].style.fontSize = (allImages[i].width / imageWidth) * dayTextSize + "px";
      allYearTexts[j].style.fontSize = (allImages[i].width / imageWidth) * yearTextSize + "px";
      allYearTexts[j].style.lineHeight = (allImages[i].width / imageWidth) * yearLineHeigh + "px";
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.datePictureHolder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.datePictureText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.datePictureText .year {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.datePictureText .day {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: to be honest, i think you could achive this with only CSS. https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: try media query or em.

Comment: @Luke that what you suggest is changing font size based on view port. The image does not resize like that.

Comment: What about drawing that as an SVG and scaling it down like an image? Otherwise, you can simply use CSS transform scale.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a bit rushed, but it might help! The green container is only there for testing purposes.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxwZge

```css
.container {
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  background:green;
}
.datePictureHolder {
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.datePictureHolder img {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.datePictureText {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center;
  padding:40% 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="datePictureHolder">
  <img class="img-responsive" alt="News Icon" src="http://shrani.si/f/u/13K/4rB6HshN/news-icon.png"/>
  <div class="datePictureText">
    <div class="year">2017</div>
    <div class="day">25. Feb</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result using either media query or using em for fonts

```css
    html {
      font-size: 16px;

      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    }

<!--- or try em for mobile web dev. 1em is 16px-->
.font-resize {
  font-size : 0.5 em;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Text</div>
```